# limit in integral! (dirac measure)

Tags: real-analysis

i have this question :

let $\phi \in C_O^\infty$ how to prove that :

lim $1/\pi\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\frac{u}{x^2+u^2}dx\rightarrow \phi(0)$ when $u\rightarrow 0^+$

thanks ...

Comment: estimate $\int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}$ using the uniform continuity of $\phi$ on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$

Comment: Not sure where "uniform" comes in; the continuity at just $0$ seems to be the main point.

Comment: What is $\;C_O^\infty\;$? It looks like infinite times differentiable functions, but what is that $\;O\;$ ?

Comment: compact support

Answer (score 1):

I think may use $\phi(x)=a(x)+b(x)$ where $a(x)$ is even, and $b(x)$ is odd so that $\int b(x)\frac{u}{x^2+u^2}dx=0=\frac{1}{\pi}b(0)$ Then just consider the even function. Use that

$$a(x)=a(0)+\frac{1}{2}x^2 a''(0)+...$$

so
$$\int a(x)\frac{u}{x^2+u}dx=2\int _0^{\infty}\left(a(0)+\frac{1}{2}x^2 a''(0)+...\right)\frac{u}{x^2+u^2}dx=\int _0^{\infty}\left((x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}a(0)+\frac{1}{2}(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} a''(0)+...\right)\frac{u}{x^2+u^2}d(x^2)$$

use $y=\frac{u^2}{x^2+u^2}$ it is

$$\int a(x)\frac{u}{x^2+u}dx=\int _0^1 \sum _{n=0} \frac{(\frac{u^2}{y}-u^2)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}a^{(2n)}(0)}{\Gamma (2n+1)}\frac{u}{\frac{u^2}{y}}u^2y^{-2}dy$$

$$=\int _0^1 \sum _{n=0} u^{2n}(1-y)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}-n+1-2}\frac{a^{(2n)}(0)}{\Gamma (2n+1)}dy=\sum _{n=0}u^{2n}Beta (n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-n)\frac{a^{(2n)}(0)}{\Gamma (2n+1)}$$

and use $\lim _{u\to 0}$ so it is

$$Beta (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\frac{a(0)}{\Gamma (1)}=\pi a(0)$$

I'm not sure whether it holds for $n>1$ that $$\int_0^1 u^{2n}(1-y)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}-n+1-2}\frac{a^{(2n)}(0)}{\Gamma (2n+1)}dy=u^{2n}Beta (n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-n)\frac{a^{(2n)}(0)}{\Gamma (2n+1)}$$ But maybe we can use $\lim_{u\to 0}$ before integration here so we do not worry about it? and if this is true, the original equation is obtained. Hope it helps.